# Why I'm getting XMLHttpRequest is not defined?

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code

I'm new developing Angular apps. I have made an app that uses Angular, TypeScript and bundle everything using webpack.

In short story this is what I get
[image]

This is my launch.json file

```
 {
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/main.ts",
        "outFiles": [
          "${workspaceRoot}/dist/main.js"
        ],
        "sourceMaps": true
    }
```

I have installed the npm for xmlhttprequest but I still get the same result.

Why I'm getting XMLHttpRequest is not defined?

Comment: npm cache clean & npm install. Would you run both of these commands?

Comment: @AnkitKapoor I did, but I got the same result. Thank you.

Comment: There could be issue with tsconfig or webpack. You can refer to angular.io docs for configuration reference.